# Use Ctrl-Alt combination as keybinding in byobu

Tags: tmux, byobu

I am currently using the bindings below to switch between windows in byobu

```
bind-key -n C-h previous-window
bind-key -n C-l next-window
```

How can I use Ctrl-Alt instead of just Ctrl to switch windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: https://askubuntu.com/a/485606/95533

Seems not to be possible to combine Ctrl-Alt in keybindings